# Use of Contains with one Except in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get a list of Menus which does not contain "license".

```
var menus= MenuRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("license") == false)
```

But now i want to exclude one of them, ie., "licenseUser"

I need "licenseUser"  in the list.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just add in another clause: `!x.Name.Contains("license") || x.Name == "licenceUser"`

Comment: Why there is more downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var menus = MenuRepo.GetAll().Where
        (
          x => !x.Name.Contains("license") || x.Name == "licenseUser"
        );
```

(note that `a == false` when `a` is boolean is the same as `!a`, and it's shorter to write)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `OR` condition which checks whether the menu name is equal to "licenseUser":

```
var menus = MenuRepo.GetAll().Where(menu => !menu.Name.Contains("license") || menu.Name == "licenseUser");
```

Comment: Seems so... I'm upvoting yours to compensate

Comment: @Jcl licenseName != licenseUser

Comment: Ah well, yes... I wouldn't say enough for downvoting (maybe a comment indicating the typo), but yes

Comment: @Jcl I just improved it.

Comment: @DavidG Than add an answer by yourself which is not lazy ;)

Comment: @rbr94 I added the comment that everyone else seemed to copy/paste because I'm happy to help, but it's a bad question so I will not post.

Comment: For the record, I hadn't seen your comment @DavidG . I wouldn't need to copy and paste it for such an easy answer :-)

Comment: @Jcl Perhaps not, but if it's such an easy answer - why did you post? You did however post an answer that is code with no explanation. :)

Comment: @DavidG why not? Should we restrict ourselves to hard answers? Is StackOverflow only for experts? I didn't believe the answer needed more than that, taken the question... if I had thought so, I wouldn't have hesitated to add more information (which I do profusely on stack overflow)